# How to print shortcode with js in visual composer?

Tags: plugins, javascript

I need to set a different shortcode for every day of the week, so I decided to do it using Visual Composer's Raw JS.
So I want to use the javascript function getDay() to do that and print the shortcode I want for the specific day. Can this be done and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that you've asked for your answer in js but I couldn't comment to ask if you'd accept a solution written with PHP.

If you are happy to use PHP you can create a shortcode that accepts each of your shortcodes as arguments. You could even map this into visual composer with their shortcode mapping tool.

The example shortcode would look like this:

`[change_shortcode_each_day mon="short_one" tue="short_two" wed="short_three" thu="short_four" fri="short_five" sat="short_six" sun="short_seven" default="default_short"]`

note: I provided a default option just in case you don't have a shortcode for each day.

```
add_shortcode('change_shortcode_each_day', 'wpse_273181_change_shortcode_each_day');

function wpse_273181_change_shortcode_each_day($atts) {

    /**
     * You can set defaults here so you don't have to right the
     * args in the shortcode itself.
     * 
     * You cannot technically use a shortcode in a shortcode
     * so you need to type the shortcodes without the brackets
     */
    $unprepared_shortcodes = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'mon'     => '',
            'tue'     => '',
            'wed'     => '',
            'thu'     => '',
            'fri'     => '',
            'sat'     => '',
            'sun'     => '',
            'default' => '',
        ),
        $atts
    );

    //make each shortcode 'complete' e.g [short_one]
    foreach ($unprepared_shortcodes as $key => $value) {
        $prepared_shortcodes[$key] = '[' . $value . ']';
    }

    extract($prepared_shortcodes);

    $current_day = date('N');

    switch ($current_day) {
        case '1' :
            $short_to_use = $mon;
            break;
        case '2' :
            $short_to_use = $tue;
            break;
        case '3' :
            $short_to_use = $wed;
            break;
        case '4' :
            $short_to_use = $thu;
            break;
        case '5' :
            $short_to_use = $fri;
            break;
        case '6' :
            $short_to_use = $sat;
            break;
        case '7' :
            $short_to_use = $sun;
            break;
    }

    /**
     * check to make sure the we have a shortcode for the day
     * if we don't use the default.
     * 
     * return false if both short_to_use and default are 'blank'
     */

    if($short_to_use == '[]' && $default != '[]') {
        $short_to_use = $default;
    } else if ($short_to_use == '[]' && $default == '[]') {
        return false;
    }

    //if we're still here do the shortcode
    return do_shortcode($short_to_use);
}
```

Comment: very nice, but where can i add my php code to make this work?

Comment: Thanks, you can add this to your themes (or child-themes) functions.php and then use it like any other shortcode.